# JS: does recursive require a `return`?

Tags: javascript

I know the best way to handle this would be in a loop but how would I do this in a recursive manner?  When I call `this.findName` again, do I have to `return` after it?  Or do I exclude the '`return` ?

```
names = [ // 50+ names in array ]

findName() {
   
     if (names[0]) {
        if (names[0].includes("XX") {
            names.shift();
            this.findName();
            return;
        }
     } else {
       return "DONE!"
     }

}
```

Comment: If you don't return the value from the recursion, then, you don't return a value. Just think of having two functins `a = () => { return b(); }` and `b = () => { 4; return;}` calling `a()` will still get you `undefined` because that's what `b` produces. It's *the same thing* if you recursively call a function - if the call produces `undefined` that's what you return in the end.

Comment: so I should `return this.findName()` then, correct?

Comment: Yes. Because you want to delegate the computation to the recursive call and return whatever that returns.

Comment: As long as you also remember _what_ you're returning: the only real value that findName will be returning is the string `"DONE!" which is not what a function called "find name" tells us it will be returning.

Comment: you do not want to mutate `names` using `.shift` as part of the recursive process. `names` should have the same contents after `findName` finishes running.

Comment: To clarify, the code after running the function will still run when it comes back from the inner function call.

Comment: @Mulan why is that?

Comment: IIs there a reason you're doing this recursively (a very bad way, for many reasons, one of which is you can crash your program if the array is too large) rather than the clean, nondestructive and idiomatic `names.find(e => e.includes("XX"))`? If you're trying to learn recursion, best to do it with a problem that actually motivates it properly rather than one that teaches misuse. Other problems: `names` is global and the function should accept a parameter rather than rely on a special global name, making it brittle and impossible to reuse. No need to return a magic string.

Comment: @ggorlen I assume OP is trying to get the hang of recursion.

Answer (score 0):

Beside mutating the original data, you need another else part or reorder the structure by taking the exit condition first and then check if the string contains a wanted pattern and return this or return the result of the recursive call.

```js
const
    names = ['jane', 'bob', 'mary', 'klaus', 'sue', 'fred'];

function findName() {   
    if (!names[0]) return "DONE!";
    if (names[0].includes("ue")) return names[0];
    names.shift();
    return findName();
}

console.log(findName());
```

Nonmutating approach

```js
function findName(names, pattern) {   
    if (!names.length) return;
    if (names[0].includes(pattern)) return names[0];
    return findName(names.slice(1), pattern);
}

console.log(findName(['jane', 'bob', 'mary', 'klaus', 'sue', 'fred'], 'xx'));
console.log(findName(['jane', 'bob', 'mary', 'klaus', 'sue', 'fred'], 'ue'));
```

Comment: But also note that arrays have a [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) function, so that no one needs to ever write this kind of code: it's built-in and lets you do this with a single line: `const name = names.find(n => n.includes("..."))`.

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans, yes, but op asks for a *recursive* approach.

Comment: I know, but since we'd never use this in the real world, pointing out the real world solution as well will still benefit future readers.

Comment: true, better to return undefined, false, or null, since returning a string implies a name was actually found. Or throw a new Error, but that's pretty overkill.